# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue set]

Tags: swift, xcode, exception

### Scenario

I have a SwiftUI app that has been working perfectly fine.
I upgrade Xcode to 13.2.1 and I'm able to launch the application but when I navigate to a certain part of the application I'm getting this error on device and during SwiftUI preview.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001bd9590'
```

### Feedback / Assistance

Can anyone provide instructions / steps to debug this?
How can I find out what is `instance 0x600001bd9590` and who is setting the `NSInvalidArgumentException`

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001bd9590'
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/m1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NT-dfyuqrdtadtqdkaxajldzwimkhru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/NT/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot//System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PreviewsInjection.framework/PreviewsInjection DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/m1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NT-dfyuqrdtadtqdkaxajldzwimkhru/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/NT/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1803e1174 __exceptionPreprocess + 216
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x180193384 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1803f0530 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1803e53fc ___forwarding___ + 1408
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803e743c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   UIFoundation                           0x18410cc7c -[NSCoreTypesetter _NSFastDrawString:length:attributes:paragraphStyle:typesetterBehavior:lineBreakMode:rect:padding:graphicsContext:baselineRendering:usesFontLeading:usesScreenFont:scrollable:syncAlignment:mirrored:boundingRectPointer:baselineOffsetPointer:drawingContext:] + 3820
6   UIFoundation                           0x18410d6c0 -[NSCoreTypesetter _stringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:graphicsContext:forceClipping:attributes:stringDrawingOptions:drawingContext:stringDrawingInterface:] + 1200
7   UIFoundation                           0x184107bf0 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 1480
8   UIFoundation                           0x184108b24 -[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:context:] + 128
9   UIKitCore                              0x18524a2b4 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 3100
10  UIKitCore                              0x18524abb8 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:] + 248
11  UIKitCore                              0x185249330 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 536
12  UIKitCore                              0x185300714 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 536
13  QuartzCore                             0x1883ad940 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 192
14  QuartzCore                             0x1884e0078 invocation function for block in CA::Layer::display_() + 52
15  QuartzCore                             0x1884d66dc -[CALayer _display] + 1688
16  QuartzCore                             0x1884e8ce4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 408
17  QuartzCore                             0x18843c04c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 516
18  QuartzCore                             0x188467860 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684
19  UIKitCore                              0x184dc48f4 _afterCACommitHandler + 104
20  CoreFoundation                         0x18034ef9c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
21  CoreFoundation                         0x180349724 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 556
22  CoreFoundation                         0x180349c84 __CFRunLoopRun + 976
23  CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
24  GraphicsServices                       0x18c03c5ec GSEventRunModal + 160
25  UIKitCore                              0x184d937ac -[UIApplication _run] + 992
26  UIKitCore                              0x184d982e8 UIApplicationMain + 112
27  SwiftUI                                0x1b99bc7f4 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 160
28  SwiftUI                                0x1b99bc750 runApp<A>(_:) + 164
29  SwiftUI                                0x1b94124f4 static App.main() + 80
30  NT                                     0x102d46c24 static NTApp.$main() + 100
31  NT                                     0x102d46d38 main + 76
32  dyld_sim                               0x10368dca0 start_sim + 20
33  dyld                                   0x1033d50f4 start + 520
34  ???                             0x4c15800000000000 ???

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c997ca60 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce380 pthread_kill + 256
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1800fe3d8 abort + 120
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18022de94 abort_message + 128
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18021fc98 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x180176e84 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18022d358 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x18022fd98 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1801934d4 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
9   CoreFoundation                         0x180349494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 808
10  GraphicsServices                       0x18c03c5ec GSEventRunModal + 160
11  UIKitCore                              0x184d937ac -[UIApplication _run] + 992
12  UIKitCore                              0x184d982e8 UIApplicationMain + 112
13  SwiftUI                                0x1b99bc7f4 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 160
14  SwiftUI                                0x1b99bc750 runApp<A>(_:) + 164
15  SwiftUI                                0x1b94124f4 static App.main() + 80
16  NT                                     0x102d46c24 static NTApp.$main() + 100 (NTApp.swift:10)
17  NT                                     0x102d46d38 main + 76
18  dyld_sim                               0x10368dca0 start_sim + 20
19  dyld                                   0x1033d50f4 start + 520
```

Comment: "but when I navigate to a certain part of the application" Which one?  You have a label with NSAttributedString, could you share the codes? Often, this kind of error is due to a bad parameter of wrong type.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out from your comment. I was setting in my code `coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: Color.black]` when it should be `coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]`. I needed to use `UIColor.black` not `Color`.